# Drag and Drop not working when run via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a java swing based application with a drag and drop functionality. When I run this application via cmd everything is working fine. But when I run the same application via eclipse the 'drag and drop' functionality is not working. What could be the problem ?

```
txtrDragYourFile.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent evt) {
        try {
            evt.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
            List<File> droppedFiles = (List<File>) evt
                    .getTransferable().getTransferData(
                            DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            for (File file : droppedFiles) {
                txtrDragYourFile.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("File path is '" + file.getPath() + "'.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well while running Eclipse as administrator. Running eclipse normally solved the problem for me.

Comment: Is this a bug from Eclipse? I had the same problem and it took me 2 hours to find out why it occurs. I just thought none of the examples I found all across the internet are working...
**Note:** Yes this happened just now in 2017 with Eclipse Oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with eclipse-java-neon-1. After upgrading to newest version the problem was gone.